excel copy a graph from one worksheet to a second and automatically graph the data in the second worksheet instead of the first
An excel workbook includes 7 worksheets, each containing 20 pairs of x,y data which I wish to graph on a single graph for each worksheet. The data in each worksheet are entered as multiple series; they are not in a single, contiguous matrix because the X values in each x,y pair differ. The data are in the same locations in each worksheet.
With the least amount of effort, in excel rather than writing VBA code if possible, I’d like to create a graph for one worksheet and simply copy it to the others to process the different data on each worksheet. But when I do this, the graph retains sheet! References to the original worksheet rather than the one to which the graph was copied.
I saved a chart as a template, but cannot find how to copy the template into a new worksheet. Also copied a chart, tried both formatting and formula "paste special" options, but the data from the original chart is still retained.

You normally don't copy a template into a worksheet, but copy the data into the template

Create a master template worksheet that has the data structure and chart.  Copy the sheet to create a new Worksheet and then fill in your data from one of the existing sheets.

cybernetic nomad, copying the data into the template is as almost laborious as creating a new chart from scratch.  Frank Ball, copying original_sheet to new_sheet leaves me with a graph whose 20 series entries (series name, series X values and series Y values) all refer to the original sheet, as in original_sheet!$A$2$:$A20. I would have to manually change original_sheet to new_sheet 60 times! Isn't there an easier way?

Found the answer. Right click the worksheet tab containing the original graph which uses only data on that same worksheet. From the pop-up that appears, select "Move or Copy", select the worksheet with the original graph, and check "Create a Copy". A new worksheet will appear which is a copy of the original except that its name is that of the original to which a (2) has been appended. The graph on the (2) worksheet uses only data on the (2) worksheet. The worksheet can be renamed and the graph on the renamed worksheet will still reference data on the renamed worksheet only.
